# Characterization of identity component of $O(p,q)$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, connectedness, quadratic-forms

For $p+q=n$ let $O(p,q)$ be the group of matrices $P\in GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ such that $PI_{(p,q)}P^t = I_{(p,q)}$ with
$$
I_{(p,q)} =
\begin{pmatrix}
I_p & 0 \\
0 & -I_q
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
I know that this group has four connected components. I want to prove the following equality that characterize the component containing the identity which, I saw, is called $SO^+(p,q)$ with
$$
SO^+(p,q) = \left\{
\begin{pmatrix}
A & B \\
C & D
\end{pmatrix}
\in SO(p,q) \mid
\det A > 0
\right\}
$$
such that $A$ is a $p \times p$ matrix and $D$ is a $q \times q$ matrix.
I also know, by computing with block decomposition, that the condition of being in $O(p,q)$ implies that $|\det A| \geq 1$ and $|\det D| \geq 1$.

Comment: What kind of characterization are you looking for?

Comment: @CaptainLama the equality involving the block matrix and $\det A > 0$ condtition.

Comment: So you're not looking for a characterization, but for the proof of the characterization you already know, right?

Comment: @CaptainLama Yes that's it I want the proof of the equality of the two sets. I think I may edit the question to make it clearer.

Comment: Just take the four (known) components of $O(p,q)$ and see in which one the identity is. For references see for example [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indefinite_orthogonal_group).